# Angular: data passed from another component becomes undefined on the page reload

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular app, I need a component to pass data to another component which do not have parent child relationship.I have an `Orders table` in one component with each row representing an order. When user clicks on any specific row, I need navigation to OrderDetails component& pass the order object representing the clicked row along with it

validation.component.html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let order of allOrders" (click)="onNavToOrderDetails(order)">
    <td>{{order.id}}</td>
 </tr>
```

validation.component.ts

```
onNavToOrderDetails(order) {
    this.router.navigate(['orderdetails'], { state: {data: order} });
 }
```

orderdetails.component.ts

```
   order;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.order=history.state.data;
   console.log(this.order);
  }
```

orderdetails.component.html

```
<p>{{order.id}}</p>
```

`orderdetails.component.html` displays order id when navigated from `validation.component.html` but refreshing the orderdetails page  cause order id to disappear. I understand on the page refresh `history.state.data` becomes undefined but how to get around this issue? Since the app is a SPA, storing the data from the `validationcomponent` to a service and using that service in the `orderdetailscomponent` won't work either.

Page refresh means reloading the entire angular app ,and order object stored in the serivce by the validation componentwill also disappear. How to solve this issue? I want previously stored data in a serivce to stay unaffected and display it again on page reload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways to handle it:

1. Use `sessionStorage` (don't go for localStorage) , but then make sure to maintain sessionStorage data as per the scenarios

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   if(history.state.data){
     this.order=history.state.data;
     sessionStorage.setItem('order_page_info', JSON.stringyfy(this.order));
   }else{
     this.order = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('order_page_info'))
   }
}
```

2. Use Cache (not recommended)
3. Rather than passing entire data, pass the `id` as router data and make server call to fetch details for the `id`. This would maintain `id` in url and so you can fetch details on refresh by calling the server

Comment: Even If I pass just Id ,it would still be lost on page refresh right?

Comment: @Arjun not if you pass it as querystring (3rd option)

Answer (score 1):

try putting ngOnChanges

ngOnChanges detects changes from other component specially from api call of services

```
ngOnChanges(){
 this.order=history.state.data
}
```